# .click() срабатывает сам по себе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю меню для мобилок и на открытие меню поставил такой код:

```
$('.mobil-menu-but').click(function () {    //открытие меню на мобильных
    var elem = $(this).parent().find('.menu-second-out');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        //elem.css('left', -400);
        elem.css('display', 'none');
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        $(this).siblings().find('.active').click();
    } else {
        //elem.css('left', 0);
        elem.css('display', 'block');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

но при открытии страницы, клик УЖЕ сработан. То есть меню открыто. Не знаю, как с этим бороться

Comment: Верстку свою проверьте. Наверняка же начальные css-классы расставить забыли...

Comment: @PavelMayorov дисплей я ставил.. Выяснил, что скрипт не срабатывает, но меню все равно открытое. Есть ссылка на пример в комментариях выше.

Answer (score 0):

ошибка крылась в скрипте, который срабатывал при изменении размера экрана. Он должен был срабатывать только если мы возвращаемся к мобильной версии. А выходило, что он срабатывал всегда при изменении размера в мобильной версии